# Django & Paypal button integration

Tags: javascript, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating a paypal payment method into my website which is working perfectly.... until I try to add a description so I can view all of the order details on the paypal invoice.

As soon as I add description (i have added order_id as an example of info i want passsing): {} to the createOrder function below, paypal fails to load:

```
<script>
    var total = '{{order.get_cart_total}}'
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        style: {
            color:  'blue',
            shape:  'rect',
        },

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value:parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
                    },
                    description: {
                        order_id
                    },
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
        submitFormData()
            });
        }

    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

**in console i get the following errors:**

[image: errors]

**I have added the settings below to my settings.py file:**

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actions.order.create(` and `actions.order.capture(` are deprecated

See [the standard checkout integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) for information on how to integrate with two backend routes that create and capture from a server. The samples there are in node.js, but these two routes (which return only JSON) can of course be implemented in any environment, including python/django.

If `order_id` is your own unique order ID (never before used for a payment that completed successfully), typically the best field to pass this value in is `invoice_id`. After a successful payment, duplicate/repeat payments for the same invoice_id are blocked by default, and this is useful to prevent the possibility of accidental double payments.

Comment: Okay thank you, guess I need a tutorial to try integrate the more recent code then

Comment: I did try the most recent integration but I kept getting errors such as ,"/my-server/capture-paypal-order/ does not exist but I cannot find any good enough guide to take me through all of this step by step  maybe you know one ?

Comment: Also can I make this work with my current cart and checkout which has been coded to pull data using JS? I followed a tutorial to build ecommerce into a project but it was from 2020, I'm hoping I don't have to rebuild everything

Comment: It doesn't exist because you haven't created and implemented such a route yet (though you can name the path something else). The routes must obtain an access token and then call the v2/checkout/orders API to create and capture an order, respectively.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to do alot of research, I'm very new to ecommerce side of things. Seems there are no simple step by step guides to follow, I haven't found one that tells you how or where to implement a route

Comment: Specifics of how to implement a web route are environment/framework-specific, so you'll get that from django documentation. Conceptually what you come up with should do the same thing as the backend sample at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , just with django+python instead of express+node

Comment: Hi Preston PHX I am still very much struggling, I managed to get my current smart button to pass the payment successfully to PayPal including the order ID for reference but I am not completely  content with this even if it is enough for what I am building. I would like to integrate it in the most latest way. Would it be possible If you had time of course, for me to send you my code snippets and maybe you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: My usecase for the button's is basic in my eyes, you may see it differently. I have built a website for a family member to sell their photographic prints, all data gets stored on djangos back end when a print is successfully sold. No complexities, just process order, order recieved, order printed and posted as per shipping address.  So maybe this would be enough for my use case; https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client ?

Comment: That is the same integration as what is documented at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ -- both are frontend JS code that call two backend routes to create and capture the order. You need to build these routes, and have them be available at the paths your JS fetches from.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge, and know that i appreciate you replying.Is there a simple way to explain what "building the route means?"

Comment: I do not work with django but https://www.google.com/search?q=django+create+json+backend+route is the place to start

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX , I am sorry to reignite this post, but could you clarify what you meant when you spoke about order_id / invoice_id ? At the moment I have everything working..... many thanks to you and all your advice by the way... I have a unique order_id which is created on my backend after order is approved, i also generate a transaction_id... Should I be letting paypal create this transaction_id and how should I do that?

Comment: If you have your own unique id, add this in the purchase_units[0].invoice_id .  Duplicate captures for a previously captured invoice_id are blocked by default (to prevent duplicate payments)